Integrating $\int_{1}^{2} \ln\left(1 + x^{2} - x\right){\rm d}x$ using Feynman's Trick
I want to evaluate
$$
\int_{1}^{2} \ln\left(1 + x^{2} - x\right)
\,{\rm d}x
$$
using Feynman's Trick but can't figure out how.
I have tried putting

$t$ instead of $1$
or putting $t\left(x^{2} - x\right)$ instead of $x^{2} - x$

but I got  stuck after the partial differentiation.

I know "Feynman's trick" only from the big bang theory where Howard Wolowitz mentioned it.

why do you want to solve it using Feynman's trick?

That would be $t+x^2- x$ then if you replace 1 with t.

Did you try the substitution $t=1+x^2-x$ ?

@SineoftheTime i know it probably isn't the best thing to do here but i just wanted to try it out

Integration by parts is much easier!

Let $$I(a) = \int_{1}^2 \ln(x^2-x+a)dx$$ if we differentiate under the integral sign we get $$I'(a) = \int_{1}^2\frac{dx}{x^2-x+a}$$This is a standard integral so you just have to show $$I'(a)=\frac{2 \left(\arctan\left(\frac{3}{\sqrt{4a - 1}}\right) - \arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{4a - 1}}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{4a - 1}}$$Lastly, you integrate that expression back (it is a lengthy process but not that complicated) to conclude $$I(a)=-\frac{2 \sqrt{4a - 1} \left(\operatorname{arccot}\left(\sqrt{4a - 1}\right) - \arctan\left(\frac{3}{\sqrt{4a - 1}}\right)\right) - 3 \ln\left(a + 2\right) + \ln\left(a\right)}{2} + C$$
To find the $C$ you must evaluate your original integral for some $a$ and equate it to the expression above, the easiest is $a=1/4$ so $$I(1/4)=-2 + \ln(27/4)=\frac{1}{2}(\ln(1/4)-3\ln(1/4+2))+C=\ln(27/4)+C \implies C=-2$$ The only thing left is evaluating $I(1)=\frac{1}{6}(\sqrt{3} π + 9 \ln(3))-2$

where the a is coming from?

@Bogaso Feynman's trick consists in adding a new variable to the original integral (in this case $a$) to differentiate under the integral sign and evaluate that expression instead, then you can integrate back and get the value of the original integral.
